# EMI formula with same installment amount

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$Installment Amount = \frac {P*i*(1 + i)^n}{(1 + i)^n - 1}$$

```
            where i  =  interest rate per installment payment period,  
            n =  number of Installments,  
            P  = principal amount of the loan
```

In the followed formula I want to take off only $i$ in one side of the equality, that is $i = ....$. I mean in my project installment amount, number of installments and
principal amount of the loan are given. I’d like to know the interest rate while the others are given.

I cannot do it since I cannot sever all ties due to power operation.

For example, if I change only $n$, I wanna get new value of $i$ without changing installment amount.

Comment: I shall post an answer tomorrow morning. Here, it is dinner time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k=\frac {\text Installment Amount} P$ an we nee to solve for $i$ the equation
$$k= \frac {i\,(1 + i)^n}{(1 + i)^n - 1}$$ This is a polynomial in $i$ of degree $(n+1)$ which cannot be solved as soon as $n>3$. Then, numerical should be used.

On this site, I addressed this problem several times but I prefer to work using my latest approach.

Howevr, we can obtain good approxiamtions. Since $i\ll 1$, expand the rhs as a Taylor series built at $i=0$. This will give
$$\frac {i\,(1 + i)^n}{(1 + i)^n - 1}=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{ (n+1)}{2 n}i+\frac{ \left(n^2-1\right)}{12 n}i^2+\frac{
   \left(1-n^2\right)}{24 n}i^3+\frac{ \left(-n^4+20 n^2-19\right)}{720
   n}i^4+\frac{ \left(n^4-10 n^2+9\right)}{480 n}i^5+\frac{\left(2 n^6-147
   n^4+1008 n^2-863\right)}{60480 n}i^6+O\left(i^7\right)$$ Now, let us use series reversion to get, as an *approximation*,
$$\color{blue}{i=t-\frac{n-1}{6}  t^2+\frac{(n-1) (2 n+1)}{36}  t^3-\frac{((n-1) (2 n+1) (11
   n+7)) }{1080}t^4+\frac{(n-1) (2 n+1)^2 (13 n+11) }{6480}t^5-\frac{(n-1) (2 n+1)
   (3 n+1) (50 n^2+89n +41) }{90720}t^6+\cdots}$$ where $\color{blue}{t=\frac{2 (k n-1)}{n+1}}$

Let us try with $k=\frac 1 {100}$ and $n=120$. The above formula should give
$$i=\frac{61848483921894776}{19860367071437578125}\approx 0.003114166$$ while the exact solution, obtained by Newton method, would be $0.003114182$.

For sure, using more terms would give still better results.